# django rest framework an always sorting field

Tags: django, sorting, django-rest-framework

I want to have a fixed sorting field applied to all custom sortings. To be more specific imagine we have a list of employees, if user choose this form be sorted by hire_date, I want the result be sorted by hire_date and employee_id together. I mean each ordering should be ordered by employee_id inside! For example if we have 5 employees hired today, if hire_date is the sorting field, these 5 be sorted by employee_id and for the other days the same story.

using the following is not the cure. It only sorts them on employee_id when no ordering is set:

```
queryset = models.Employee.objects.order_by('id')
```

And this one's result is same as previous:

```
filter_backends = (CustomFilterSetBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
custom_filters = (
    ........
)
ordering_fields = (............)
ordering = ('id',)
```

tnx a million

Answer (score 5):

In model add this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ......
    ......

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-hire_date','employee_id']
```

It will order by `hire_date` and if dates are same then `employee_id`.

Comment: you are setting hire-date in default ordering, I mentioned the second ordering is determined by the user. so I want user chosen ordering field be merged to employee_id and user ordering field is not always the same @Astik-Anand

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i had got back while working so , there are few solutions you can adopt ,
In your Employee model class you can do these ,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    class Meta:
    # Latest by hire_date ascending, employee_id ascending.

        ordering = ['hire_date', 'employee_id']
```

And also you can do some thing like these at query end ,

```
from your_app.models import Employee
queryset = models.Employee.objects.order_by('employee_id')
```

Third solution can be combined form of first two solutions as i mentioned and as you described in comment that can be like ,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    class Meta:
    # Latest by hire_date ascending, employee_id ascending.

        ordering = ['employee_id']
```

Now when you fetch employee you should do these ,
(i am assuming these from views.py file)

```
from your_app.models import Employee
queryset = models.Employee.objects.order_by('hire_date')
```

Let me know if any problem in third approach.

Comment: your first solution has the same problem as I mentioned commented for @Astik-anand and about your second one, I traced for the raw query submitted for the querysets, and I realized the ordering field specified in queryset initializing is replaced by what user has chosen

Comment: @HamedSalimian see third approach